# R reticulate - recordlinkage package installed in r script but not importing in python script

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I've tried

```
py_install("recordlinkage")
```

It returns this error :

> py_install("recordlinkage")
>   Collecting package metadata: ...working... done
>   Solving environment: ...working... failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - recordlinkage
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
>   looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

So I went to https://anaconda.org and searched **recordlinkage** and it returned **r-recordlinkage**

Then I did py_install("r-recordlinkage"), it installed it beautifully.
When I do

```
import r-recordlinkage
```

in the .py script it says

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

what am I missing here? :/

Comment: According to Anaconda, [r-recordlinkage](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-recordlinkage) is an R package not Python module. But a different module by different authors is available in [Python](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html). Simply remove `r-` in name as hyphens are never used in Python and R names (Anaconda likely uses this to differentiate the version and only for their install caller).

Comment: removing the hiphen import recordlinkage gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recordlinkage'

Comment: Did you install it before importing: `py_install("recordlinkage")` or `pip install recordlinkage`?

Comment: py_install("recordlinkage") is giving the error that i described in the question. and pip install recordlinkage says Requirement already satisfied on multiple lines

Comment: and conda install recordlinkage gives the same error as py_install("recordlinkage")

Comment: Sorry I misread first attempt. Likely, the Python version of `recordlinkage` is not available among the [Anaconda packages](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/repo).

Answer (score 1):

Just write: 
"`pip install recordlinkage`"
For me, it works!.